# Trying to call a VC method after initializing it from scratch ( Obj-C )

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I am initializing a VC from my storyboard like so :

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle: nil];
EstablishCallViewController *establishCallViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"EstablishCallViewController"];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow setRootViewController:establishCallViewController];
```

I set the VC `establishViewController` to my `rootViewController`, and then I would like to call the method `establishVoipCallAndShowCallViewController()` like so:

```
[establishCallViewController establishVoipCallAndShowCallViewController:EKandyOutgingVoIPCallOptions_startCallWithVideo];
```

However, this returns

> No visible @interface for 'EstablishViewCallController' declares the selector 'establishVoipCallAndShowCallViewController:'

Hmmm, no fair! In my `establishViewCallController.h` file I have :

```
@interface EstablishCallViewController : UIViewController
  -(void)establishVoipCallAndShowCallViewController:(enum EKandyOutgingVoIPCallOptions)outgoingCallOption;
@end
```

So why isn't it detecting this instance method? Or better yet, how can I call this instance method properly?

**The method (truncated) I'm trying to call**

```
-(void)establishVoipCallAndShowCallViewController:(EKandyOutgingVoIPCallOptions)outgoingCallOption
  {
    ...
```

Comment: `-(void)establishVoipCallAndShowCallViewController;` VS (what I guess) --`(void) establishVoipCallAndShowCallViewController:(Something)someParamter;` not the same signature.

Comment: @Larme Hmm.. any tips on how to properly write my .h file? The parameter I'm passing is an `enum`

Comment: Something like `-(void) establishVoipCallAndShowCallViewController:(EKandyOutgingVoIPCallOptions)option;` in your .h file. And  `-(void) establishVoipCallAndShowCallViewController:(EKandyOutgingVoIPCallOptions)option{}` in your .m file

Comment: @Y.Bonafons Hmm.. that's what I was thinking too. I tried that, and updated answer above. What's more, is that writing that in the `.h` causes the Warning : Declaration of 'enum EKandyOutgingVoIOPCallOptions' will not be visible outside of this function.

Comment: `-(void)stablishVoipCallAndShowCallViewController:(enum EKandyOutgingVoIPCallOptions)outgoingCallOption;` => `-(void)stablishVoipCallAndShowCallViewController:(EKandyOutgingVoIPCallOptions)outgoingCallOption;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's seems you forgot the param for establishVoipCallAndShowCallViewController at the .h file

Comment: Per @Larme 's comment, I added what I thought would be the parameter and updated my answer above but it still provides the same error.